# VBA copying and pasting values and ColumnWidths together

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

The issue is to paste the copied range into another sheet with the original format (e.g.source columns width to the target column). I have tried to include the code "Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths" in combination with "Paste:=xlPasteValues". But it wasn't successful. For example, by writing ".PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths" only yields no copied values.

```
  With wq.Sheets("Table 5").Range("A1:W51").Copy
  End With

  With ws.Range("A6")
 .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
  End With
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on "xlPasteColumnwidths" and can my code be more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442250/error-on-xlpastecolumnwidths-and-can-my-code-be-more-efficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is:

```
 With wq.Sheets("Table 5").Range("A1:W51").Copy
 ws.Range("A01").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 ws.Range("A01").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
 ws.Range("A:W").EntireRow.AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: I think you'll find that's an alternative solution to your requirement, rather than an answer to the question you actually asked... You asked how to paste values and columnwidths. Autofitting columnwidths is different from pasting them...

Comment: You are right in fact. Shall I delete the question?